# Is there any other way of splitting below column?

Tags: python

```
Average_Cost
₹200
₹100
₹150
₹250
₹200
₹220
```

The above one is the column and I want to remove '₹' and display only numeric number iI used split function and wrote the code as shown below.

```py
j=[]
k=train['Average_Cost']
for i in k:
    l=i.split('₹')
    j.append(l[1])
train['Average_cost']=j
```

And I got error as

> list index out of range

Comment: Looks like there is a line where '₹' does not occur.

Comment: if `str.split()` doesn't match against anything, it will return a list containing the whole given string.

Comment: Can you give us the output of `print(train['data'])`?

Answer (score 2):

Use `str.lstrip('₹')`

**Ex:**

```
train['Average_Cost'] = train['Average_Cost'].str.lstrip('₹')
```